# Python before writing to CSV file check if column data is present

Tags: python, csv

Hi have dictionary data as shown:

```
{'Count': 5, '_id': {'ele_id': ['17cd-4a9f-9671-80eda11f9c53'], 'day': '2015-09-22'}, 'name': 'Default Astn'}
{'Count': 2, '_id': {'ele_id': ['17cd-4a9f-9671-80eda11f9c53'], 'day': '2015-09-18'}, 'name': 'Default Astn'}
{'Count': 1, '_id': {'ele_id': ['ccdf-4e0b-a87c-4e7738a0ed33'], 'day': '2015-09-14'}, 'name': 'sharepoint Astn'}
{'Count': 1, '_id': {'ele_id': ['2b9f-436b-a2ff-c4bc4059a9c8'], 'day': '2015-09-14'}, 'name': 'JPL Astn'}
{'Count': 2, '_id': {'ele_id': ['17cd-4a9f-9671-80eda11f9c53'], 'day': '2015-09-14'}, 'name': 'Default Astn'}
```

Want to write to CSV with columns and data as below:

```
Date        Name           Count
2015-09-22  Default Astn     5
2015-09-18  Default Astn     2
2015-09-14  sharepoint Astn  1
            JPL Astn         1
            Default Astn     2
```

Problem I'm facing is for 3 row, just add 2 and 3rd column if 1st column is already same.
My code is as below

```
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    fieldnames = ['Date','Name','Count']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for line in data:
            writer.writerow({'Date' : line['_id']['day'],'Name' : line['name'], 'Count':line['Count']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ..... haven't tested but I think the logic remains the same......

```
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
fieldnames = ['Date','Name','Count']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    prev_date = ''
    for line in data:
        curr_date = line['_id']['day']
        if curr_date == prev_date:
            writer.writerow({'Date' : '','Name' : line['name'], 'Count':line['Count']})
        else:
            writer.writerow({'Date' : curr_date,'Name' : line['name'], 'Count':line['Count']})
            prev_date = curr_date
```

Comment: Thank you for the logic it worked. Also with same respective is it possible  increase the width of the each column when writing header .

Comment: @kittu It does work this way, it depends on the application(MS Excel, etc) with which you are opening your csv file.